# Eclipse Juno Hangs

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am really desperate to install eclipse on ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit). The problem is, eclipse hangs when the splashscreen shown. I run eclipse with -debug option and got following log message :

```
Start VM: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.class.path=/home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-debug
-clean
-clearPersistedState
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.class.path=/home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
Install location:
    file:/home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
Splash location:
    /home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/home/iwan/dev-new/eclipse/.options loaded
Time to load bundles: 70
Starting application: 11447
```

My java version is

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: From where did you get this copy of Eclipse? What was the filename? Did you unpack it to somewhere new? Have you tried a newer JRE (Java 6 was EOL a year ago)? A newer Eclipse (Kepler SR2 is what's current)?

Comment: i got from eclipse.org. Yes i unpack to new dir. Currently i am trying with java 7, but no luck. Now trying kepler.

Comment: Here is the log message:

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb67c9c99, pid=30041, tid=3075901120
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x1e0c99]  gtk_text_buffer_get_tag_table+0x99
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

Comment: Still no luck with kepler :(

Comment: Which file did you download?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (32 bit)

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz

Comment: i just try eclipse with KDE & GNOME 3 works pretty well. Something trouble with my Unity ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the options, nothing worked. So I finally figured out the solution:
I removed all JRE installations in my C:\Program Files and C:|Program Files(x86) folders. Installed a new JDK 7 package, copied the fullpath of the JDK7\bin folder and appended it at the end of the "Path" variable under 'Environment variables' of my Windows 7 pc. Then restarted everything, so it worked.